# Resource not found in JFrame java app

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I am currently building a small Java game using JFrama. I got some aliens that fall and they are all images and they load correctly. Now I want to put and image for the player but when i did this my whole project burned out. I get an exception like this

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gamepackage.Game.draw(Game.java:50)
    at gamepackage.Game.paint(Game.java:45)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to figure out where the problem is and I end up here 
`ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(player));`

and `player` is `private String player = "../img/player_64.png";`

The image for the alien is loaded in the same way and both pictures are in the same direction. So I tried a lot of thing but nothing worked so far.

Comment: The line you use to load the image should throw an exception; try catching it.

Comment: So I will catch the this I pasted above. I don't want this. I want to lead the image correctly because I need it :/

Comment: `"../img/player_64.png"` What is the package of the class?  What is the location of the resource in relation to the class?  How could you think we could help you solve this *without* such fundamental information?  We're fresh out of magic..

Comment: I expected that someone who already did this will tell if there is some common mistake that is made for an error like this because I verified that the resource is where it should be. Finally I ended up rewriting the whole class ( almost the whole game ) from scratch and now It's running soothly. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the specification for `getResource()`:

> Returns: A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found

You should print the URL object returned by this method. Chances are it's null, which means that your path is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I printed the path and the url is correct the file is there. But for some reason my Player class is not knowing that the image is there